# Magernto Authorize.net payment NoSuchEntityException

Tags: magento2, authorize.net

The issue is with Authorize.net payment, when I click on place order I get an error:

"no such entity with cartId"

This is happening only if I set the payment option to authorize and capture if I set it to authorize only it's OK.

Also in the main store, it's working fine, the issue is with other stores.

Order is created in admin but stays on pending.

Looks like a cart quote issue getting inactive only in authorize and capture method.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX25Y.jpg)

Error on screen:

```
<response>
<message>No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue</message>
<parameters>
<fieldName>cartId</fieldName>
<fieldValue>107</fieldValue>
</parameters>
<trace>
#0 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(164): Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('cartId', '107') 
#1 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->getActive('107') 
#2 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callParent('getActive', Array) #3 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('107') 
#4 /var/www/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getActive', Array, Array) 
#5 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Cart/CartTotalRepository.php(89): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->getActive('107') 
#6 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository->get('107') 
#7 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository\Interceptor->___callParent('get', Array) 
#8 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('107') 
#9 /var/www/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Cart/CartTotalRepository/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('get', Array, Array) 
#10 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php(144): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository\Interceptor->get('107') 
#11 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php(166): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->getPaymentInformation('107') #12 [internal function]: Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->getPaymentInformation('E8MYixrI58pSjig...') 
#13 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#14 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy)) 
#15 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#16 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) 
#17 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#18 /var/www/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) 
#19 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(137): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#20 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() 
#21 /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) 
#22 {main}
</trace>
</response>
```

Thank you,
Eran